# Laravel how can get this relation

Tags: php, laravel

Consider a `digital store`

**Definition:**

```
Buyer->all buyer
Products->all products
Downloads->store those products that buyer bought
```

a `Buyer` can buy a `Product` and it store in `Downloads`, now I want to show to buyer list of downloads.

**ProductController.php**

```
public function buyerproducts()
{
    $user = auth()->guard('buyer')->user();
    if ($user) {
        $files = Product::where('deleted', 0)
            ->where('deleted', 0)
            ->with('files', 'province:id,name', 'city:id,name')
            ->get();

        // and here I got a loop.. to add some extra data
        return response()->json(['data' => $files], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['success' => 'no content'], 204);
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
function files()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Download', 'App\Buyer', 'id', 'product_id', 'buyer_id', 'id');
}
```

But it return all data, not what buyer bought. any idea?
*Note, that I have to get this data in product controller not download.*

---

**Products:**

```
-----------------------
|id | name  | seller_id  |
-----------------------
| 1 | bmw   |    1     |
-----------------------
| 2 | benz  |    1     |
-----------------------
| 2 | reno  |    2     |
-----------------------
```

**Downloads:**

```
------------------------------
|id | product_id  | buyer_id  |
------------------------------
| 1 |     1     |      1      |
------------------------------
| 2 |     1     |      2      |
------------------------------
| 3 |     2     |      22     |
------------------------------
```

**Buyer:**

```
------------------------------
|id | name     |       email  |
------------------------------
| 1 |     john     |      @   |
------------------------------
| 2 |     mike     |      @   |
------------------------------
| 3 |     dave     |      @  |
------------------------------
```

Comment: Please can you show the definitions/migrations for these tables.

Comment: @Rwd I added table view, hope it make this question clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HasManyThrough` relationship is expecting to go through 2 `hasMany` relationships, however, looking at your table definition, the first relationship is `hasMany` but the second would be a `belongsTo`. Since both keys relate to a single row in a different table (both `belongsTo`) we can instead create a `belongsToMany` relationship instead and treat the `downloads` table as a pivot.

---

There are a couple of different ways you can go about this.

Firstly, I would suggest setting up the relationships between `Buyer` and `Product` (is you haven't already done so):

**Product**

```
public function buyers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Buyer::class, 'downloads')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Buyer**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'downloads')->withTimestamps();
}
```

---

Then in your controller method you could either keep the same query and use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
public function buyerproducts()
{
    $user = auth()->guard('buyer')->user();

    if ($user) {
        $files = Product::where('deleted', 0)
            ->whereHas('buyers', function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('buyers.id', $user->id);
            })
            ->with('files', 'province:id,name', 'city:id,name')
            ->get();

        // and here I got a loop.. to add some extra data
        return response()->json(['data' => $files], 200);
    }

    return response()->json(['success' => 'no content'], 204);
}
```

**or** alternatively you could not just query the products straight from the `$user` (buyer):

```
public function buyerproducts()
{
    $user = auth()->guard('buyer')->user();

    if ($user) {
        $files = $user->products()->where('deleted', 0)
            ->whereHas('buyers', function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('buyers.id', $user->id);
            })
            ->with('files', 'province:id,name', 'city:id,name')
            ->get();

        // and here I got a loop.. to add some extra data
        return response()->json(['data' => $files], 200);
    }

    return response()->json(['success' => 'no content'], 204);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Awesome answer. it return right, thing, just a little question, can I include seller data in this result?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go with getting the products as Buyer object relationship.

So you define products in Buyer.php:

```
function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Download', 'App\Product', 'id', 'buyer_id', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

And in the controller you can call it like:

```
$buyer->with([
  'products.province:id,name',
  'products.city:id,name'
  ])
    ->whereHas('products', function($query){
       $query->where('deleted', 0)
      })
    ->get()
```

then you can go with `return response()->json(['data' => $buyer->products], 200);`